# Docker recipe for .NET Core 3.1 and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a Docker recipe to run a server for .NET Core 3.1 and SQL Server. The recipe is:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 as base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ExampleProject.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./ExampleProject"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "ExampleProject" -c Release -o /app

FROM build as publish
RUN dotnet publish "ExampleProject" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ExampleProject"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "Jko3va-D9821jhsvGD"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

When I try to run this Docker instance, I get the follow error when building the SQL Server.

```
An error occurred while migrating the database.
web_1  | Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Option 'SINGLE_USER' cannot be set in database 'master'.
```

[image]

Comment: It would seem like it tries to do the migration directly in the 'master' database (which in SQL server contains all the server metadata). Not an expert on EF migrations, but you should probably point it to a separate application database.

Comment: Hopefully that's not your real password posted on the web.

Comment: It is not! I'm just starting to play with Docker and SQL Server.